# Seriealize() Aajax com problema

Tags: ajax

Tenho vários formulários em um html, e quero enviar com o Ajax cada formulário, estou usando o serialize(). Mais não está dando certo, onde estou errando?

```
 <div class="resultado_<?php $i++; echo $i ?>">
  <span class="bom"><br>Cadastro Completo</span><br>

  <form method="post" id="favoritos" novalidate="novalidate">

      <input type="hidden" name="id_empresa" value="<?php echo $row["id"]?>" class="id_empresa">

   <input type="submit" value="Favoritos">



</form>
</div>
```

Ajax

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#favoritos").submit(function() {

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'enviar_atualizar.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) { 
            // Inserting html into the result div
            $('.resultado_'+formID).html(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
            // Displaying if there are any errors
            $('.resultado_'+formID).html(error);           
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

});

retorna isso no console

Uncaught ReferenceError: formID is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente a variável `formDetails` não foi declarada ou por não estar dentro de `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` ela não tenha conseguido pegar o FORM, você pode resolver simplesmente usando assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#favoritos").submit(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'enviar_atualizar.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) { 
                // Inserting html into the result div
                $('.resultado_'+formID).html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
                // Displaying if there are any errors
                $('.resultado_'+formID).html(error);           
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

O `$(this)` vai se referir ao elemento que recebeu o evento `submit`, no caso o próprio `<FORM>`

Comment: editei minha resposta, está retornando um erro no console

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard formID não foi definido, de onde deveria vir esta var? Dê detalhes.